# Value of divergent alternating series

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

I was curious if there is any method to be able to sum series like this
$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } (-1)^n n^n$$ or similar $$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } n^n (-z)^n$$ for any value os z , I see solutions  using integrating Lambert function  but it is too complicate I try using levin transform and pade but do not work . it would be convenient to have some general method to sum divergent series like
$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } (-1)^n n^n \Gamma (n+1)=0.530056382620967931234158702$$
without the use of integrals if possible in this case

Comment: The sum certainly converges in the ring of $p$-adic integers where we set $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}n^n=\lim_{v>0,v\rightarrow 0}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}n^n$ where the limit and the notion of v converging to $0$ are both taken in the topology of $p$-adic integers. Did you want to restrict your attention to the real or complex numbers, or would a $p$-adic interpretation also be suitable?

Comment: hi@Joseph Van I was interested in acceleration or extrapolation methods that can sum these kinds of divergent sums without the need to transform the sums into integrates where it is possible.